# Modal refuses to show with if(isset)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that inserts records into the data. I have an if statement checking that if there is an error message then a modal should appear displaying the error message. This the if statement

```
if(isset($errMSG)) {
    echo
        "<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#errMSG').modal('show');
            });
        </script>";
}
```

This is the modal

```
<!--Error Message Modal-->
<div id="errMSG" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Error Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                    <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have test the if statement with an echo like this

```
if(isset($errMSG)) {
    echo 'test';
}
```

And it works. my javascript code is just not being read for the previous example

Comment: It is being read, but it is inserted before the html tag. You should insert that PHP code at the place you want this code to run. Which would be at the beginning or at the end of the body tag.

Comment: the snippet of  php code which I showed is within the body tag, and its in the place I want it to run

Comment: Is your JS code at the end of body?